# Mazda 2 - year 2018 petrol car

Tags: power

Lost power down to 20 mph.  Was checked by recovery chap running diagnostic but nothing showed up.  No light to indicate fault. Went ok when chap tried car out.

Comment: Before you go too far, maybe you can run it by a dealer and get them to test it?

Comment: Thanks for reply Mike. The trouble is no warning light stays on.  The recovery engineer said the fault can't be traced unless this happens or the log shows it had a warning. But may take it in case.